# Asp.net Web Api Attribute Routing with same actions

Tags: asp.net, url

Below is the controller which has following actions.

```
 [AttributeRouting.RoutePrefix("Resource")]
 public class LimitController : ApiController
 {
        [AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("{param}/Entity")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult EntityGet(string param)

        [AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("{param}/Entity")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult EntityPost(string param)

        [AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("{param}/Entity")]
        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult EntityUpdate(string param)

 }
```

I have put these 3 actions in my controller and placed attribute routing as per https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

But only Get Method is accessible and put and post method returns

```
   {
      "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
    }
```

Any help is much appretiated

Below are the put and post Request by postman

```
PUT /api/v1/Resource/213/Entity HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2022
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: fc0b7d89-c881-df79-0041-ca1b84ece89a

{
"RelationshipID":"4327010003000061=2107"
}
```

and POST

```
POST /api/v1/Resource/213/Entity HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2022
LicenseKey: A394F15662BE3095C4D7B51F43EAEC9ACAB6A080
Authorization: Bearer de580af5-fc58-47d5-bf4a-025070aacf97
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 05e694f0-aef5-a769-8fda-2d5538b57bd9

{
"RelationshipID":"4327010003000061=2107"
}
```

Comment: Have you added `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your WebApiConfig?

Comment: yes indeed I have added

Comment: Can you show your full request for POST & PUT please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AttributeRouting.RoutePrefix
```

is the open source version for ASP.net MVC attribute routing. Try using

```
System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix
```

and

```
System.Web.Http.Route
```

It should resolve the issue and all attributes will be routed on `HTTP` verbs